# Protecting API calls from being exposed to third parties

Tags: javascript, php, api

Recently I've created a web app which I would like to protect from people who try to get access to the data I use. So think about sensitive information that normally no one would be able to get access but me.

Right now I'm making a JavaScript `fetch` request to a `get_data.php` file in which I make a `echo(file_get_contents(https://thirdpartyapi.com))`.

The thing is that someone is stealing all this information through front-end I guess, since on the `get_data.php` I request some cookies for the requests to be executed.

How would I be able to protect such attempts of stealing my data?

Comment: Your backend could limit who gets access. There are many ways to do this. Your 1st request to the api might be for example, to provide an access token for subsequent api requests.

Comment: I thought of that but, as i understood they are getting the request response through frontend. How would an access token prevent this?

Comment: An "access token" would be a privileged set of chars that only the caller/client  would have. It would be generated by your back-end and returned on that part of the api call. How it is generated needs to be random (and unique) enough obviously. And of course, a https/ssl connection is ideal.

Comment: For any api calls subsequent, your code is so written to make the access token as also required, so your api can check if that access token is valid (exists and has not expired), to do additional functionality.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. I will try that as soon as possible and i will come back.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some kind of API think about authentification: https://jwt.io.

Comment: I thought of that but, as i understood they are getting the request response through frontend. How would an access token prevent this?